# pdoc3 incorrectly rendered Args section

Tags: python, docstring, pdoc

Recently migrated from an M1 to M2 mac.  Previous successful invocation of pdoc was on M1 with Ventura 13.6, same python version.  Is there a prerequisite I'm missing, or maybe need to downgrade a dependency, or is this due to an unreported error in my docstrings somewhere else in the module?

Example Source code:

```py
"""

  Args:  
      script_path (str, optional): the full s3 or github uri, or local path to the script you want the service to execute. Defaults to "./script.py".  

"""
```

Correctly rendered **Args** section, from previous invocation e.g.,

```html
<h2 id="args">Args</h2> 
<dl>
<dt><strong><code>script_path</code></strong> :&ensp;<code>str</code>, optional</dt>
<dd>the full s3 or github uri, or local path to the script you want the service to execute. Defaults to "./script.py".</dd>
</dl>
```

Incorrectly rendered Args section in current env:

```html
<p>Args:<br>
script_path (str, optional): the full s3 or github uri, or local path
to the script you want the service to execute. Defaults to "./script.py".
</p>
```

- pdoc version: pdoc `0.10.0`
- python version: `3.9.16`  (pyenv)
- M2 mac with os x Ventura `13.6.2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by trailing spaces after `Args:`

This fails:  `Args:`  
This succeeds:  `Args:`

I likely did a find/replace at some point that fouled everything.